# How to async load and bind XML data to TreeView?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, xaml

I bind XML file to WPF TreView using this code:

```
XmlDocument XMLdoc = new XmlDocument();
try
{
     XMLdoc.Load(file);
     XmlDataProvider provider = new XmlDataProvider();
     provider.Document = XMLdoc;
     Binding binding = new Binding();
     binding.Source = provider;
     binding.XPath = "child::node()";
     xmlTree.SetBinding(TreeView.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
}
catch (XmlException)
{
  MessageBox.Show("The XML file is invalid");
  return;
}
```

I cannot say that XML is too big but it takes a lot of time more than 1 min to bind and show XML data under WPF TreeView.

My question is: **Are there any points that we can optimize?**

(NOTE: The final idea is to show XML under WPF App.)

Comment: How big is the XML file, approximately?

Comment: @ErikDietrich. It is 138Kb. Each item has at least 4-6 levels.

Comment: if the final idea is just to "show XML" (with no editing), then would it be better to choose an alternate method?

Comment: @jberger. Well... I don't know about alternate methods... :) Could you point me exactly what you meant, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the TreeView property "VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing" to "true".

Answer (score 1):

Without having the code and XML file in front of me, I can only go by what's here, and what I see is that you're loading a somewhat complex and large XML file into memory first, and then binding the GUI to it second, all sequentially.

At some point, you're going to have to pay the piper in terms of those expensive and time-consuming operations, but you can at least make your GUI responsive while it loads.  I would investigate using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) for the loading and possibly even the binding (this is where I'd need to be looking at more to say for sure).

Here's a [blog post](http://patconroy.wordpress.com/page/2/) that talks about XMLDataProvider and Background worker, although in a slightly different context than yours.  It should give you something to work with, anyway.  The general theme here is that you want to take expensive operations and do them in the background without blocking all progress so that at least your GUI can be responsive to the user.  That is, you can have the GUI show a progress bar, an hourglass mouse icon, etc, while the expensive loading and binding occur.

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you forget to put the link after  "Here's a blog post " ... Could you edit you answer, please?

Comment: I edited it and inlined -  clicking on "blog post" will take you there.

Comment: if this is the accepted answer, then the question title is inappropriate.  **"How to async load and bind XML data to TreeView?"** OR **"How to load and bind huge XML data to TreeView?"**